# How to fix selenium "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" exception in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### **SOLVED**

When I use both arguments `--headless` and `user-data-dir`. Selenium raise `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` exception. If only 1 of them is used, then everything works as needs.

I tried to swap arguments and remove some of them.
Specified the full path to chromedriver.exe.
None of this helped.

**chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") DIDN'T HELP ME.**

```py
login = "test"
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}) 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") 
chromeOptions.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=.\cookies\\" + login) 
b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) 
b.get("https://google.com/") 
b.quit()
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I solve it by adding an argument `--remote-debugging-port=<port>`

```py
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}) 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 

chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this

chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized") 
chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chromeOptions.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=.\cookies\\test") 

b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) 
b.get("https://google.com/") 
b.quit()
```

Comment: Could you explain why this fixes it ?

Comment: @mosaad so, I have forgotten everything, but I think this fixes it because chrome can't connect to debug and you need to make it manual.

Comment: Could you please say where this code has been added? What is the name of the file?

Comment: maybe port was taken

Comment: If nothing works, try to restart your PC. Worked for me.

Comment: Hi @vffuunnyy, I'm running scripts through Organization host machine, Every Single time it triggers through Unique port. Could you please tell how to pass unique ports in this case?

Comment: For me it was the ~"set-binary-location" which I had set to specify the path of Chromedriver, but that path should really be pointing to the chrome binary itself. Hence I removed it, based on a tip from someone else here on Stackoverflow, in a thread which I couldn't find now when I looked (my browser dedicated to this prolem had 50 or so tabs, which I all got rid of now). 
All creds to the author of that comment (y).