# facing error while running the Selenium in Python (pycharm)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kushk/PycharmProjects/SeleniumPython/Multibrowser.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
  File "C:\Users\kushk\PycharmProjects\SeleniumPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\kushk\PycharmProjects\SeleniumPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\kushk\PycharmProjects\SeleniumPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\kushk\PycharmProjects\SeleniumPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kushk\PycharmProjects\SeleniumPython\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code, not just the error trace

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not exist in the code that you have written. It is in the system you are using. Try the following:

1. Restarting your computer.
2. Making sure that selenium is installed properly.
3. Making sure that chrome functions properly without the code and checking its functionality from task manager.

Regards.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I have tried above all the steps, unfortunately its not working on all of the browser supported by the selenium

Comment: The following question answers your query, I guess.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637973/how-to-fix-selenium-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-exception-in-python>

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. I figured it out, now it's running very smoothly!